# store value in variable using $_GET but its not working

Tags: php

```
http://domain.com/update.php?id=DCS013001
```

I am using get method for `store id` in variable

```
   if ($_GET['id']!="") {
    $id=$_GET['id'];
      mysql_query("DELETE FROM empmaster where empid=' ". $id. " ' ");
      header('Location:tables.php');
}
```

but its not working

Comment: Please show us your **full** and **real** code + your full error message, which you get

Comment: its not a duplicate Mr. @Rizier123

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset()`

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
echo $id;
}
```

Comment: but same code is run when we chage the  update.php?id=1

Answer (score 0):

You should add a check if it is present -

```
$id = !empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : false; // Or store anything that would be useful to $id
```

Store `$id` only if it is set else store something else or not store it. But if you don't store `$id` you have to add check for the same where ever you ar using it.